# Check whether or not a user enters in an exact string

Tags: javascript, string, validation

I want check whether or not a user enters in an exact string I'm having problems though I tried some of the advice in questions like this but I still can't get it.

```
function check() {

var ans1 ="Hey there";

  var ans2 = document.getElementById("#ans").value;

if (ans1== ans2){ alert('yes kit')}

else{alert ('no')};
}

HTML
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="Textbox" value="" id="ans"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="test" onClick=" return check()">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: `var ans2 = document.getElementById("ans").value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing # in document.getElementById, that's your mistake.

see below code for reference.

Html is ok.

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<input type="text" name="Textbox" value="" id="ans"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="test" onClick=" return check()">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

but change your javascript to this.

```
function check() {

var ans1 ="Hey there";

var ans2 = document.getElementById("ans").value;

if (ans1== ans2){ alert('yes kit')}

else{alert ('no')};

}
```

Comment: Sure thing.Im still new to stack overflow I hope that did the trick.